# A spam-flagging application has been turned on for Software Engineering

Tags: discussion, spam

For the full details, please see the discussion on Meta Stack Exchange: [Can a machine be taught to flag spam automatically?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/291301/can-a-machine-be-taught-to-flag-spam-automatically)

In short, a group of users have created an application that, historically, has much higher accuracy in identifying spam. This application has been turned on for all sites in the network.

Please direct any general discussion of this new application to the above Meta Stack Exchange discussion. Any discussion or questions as it pertains to Software Engineering is appropriate here - if it needs an answer, I can ping the right people.

Answer (score 12):

As a point of reference, we don't detect much spam on Software Engineering: [see the list here](https://metasmoke.erwaysoftware.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&title=&body=&username=&why=&site=330&feedback=&reason=&user_rep_direction=%3E%3D&user_reputation=0&commit=Search). Some sites get more, some get less, and there isn't much rhyme or reason to it.

At minimum autoflagging accuracy, we would have flagged only one post, from two months ago - [this one](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/339142) ([link for <10kers](https://metasmoke.erwaysoftware.com/post/51801)).

Comment: The reason for the low spam is likely the fact that we prevent questions from unregistered accounts. It was a measure taken to prevent low quality questions from people who didn't understand our site scope, especially before the name change from Programmers to Software Engineering. In my experience, our spam posts tend to be self-promotion of the user's own blog or the user's company's products and don't fit into the same generic spam like the post that was previously identified.

Comment: @ThomasOwens AFAIK, SO has the same feature, yet they have humongous amount of spam. I doubt that's the reason.